# Change redirect of @security annotation in Symfony2

Tags: security, symfony, redirect

I had the following annotations on my controller

```
/**
 * [...]
 * @Route("/test")
 * @Security("has_role('ROLE_USER')")
 * [...]
 */
```

When I'm not connected and trying to go on `/test`, I'm redirect to `/login`

How please can I change this and redirect to `/my_failure_url` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In security.yml

```
 firewalls:
     your_firewall_name:
     //...
         form_login:
             # the user is redirected here 
             login_path: /your_url
```

Comment: Note that this won't work for other roles as administrators. right?